# Galaxy Note Jelly Bean update India

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-note

Is there any Jelly Bean update available for Note N7000 in India?

Any one know when this update is coming?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet available in India.
[Here](http://www.sammobile.com/2013/02/18/samsung-releases-android-4-1-2-jelly-bean-update-for-the-galaxy-note-2/) you can see most of the countries are in pending list for OTA update.

If you are impatient for the update, you can grab the Asia or Germany version and manually install using the Odin method.